# Android Virtual Device Misconfigured?

Tags: java, android

I have run into a problem with the following device that comes as builtin into the AVD .

[image]

As you can see the screen size for this device is 6 inch . Resolution is 480 x 800. This can't be HDPI as it states in the picture .

The screen is 6 inches wide , with 800 pixels across , resulting in 800/6 = 133.33 DPI .

According to http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html , this should be an mdpi device taking resources from my mdpi folder , however it states this device as an hdpi device , and takes resources from hdpi folder

Any clue whats going on here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the devices u r showing are not by Android. Here many of device configuration are not defaults those someone have created.So no such question now for this case.